# mongodb error on using $unwind operator in aggregation

Tags: mongodb, exception, aggregation-framework

Here is my collection document

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [Patent] => Array
            (
                [allocation] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [r_1_a] => 17
                            )

                    )

                [pn] => US20120101874A1
                [id] => 52fb18775f44eaaf0a8b462a
            )

    )
```

I am trying to use $unwind operator with this query :

```
db.patents.aggregate([{'$unwind':'$allocation'}]);
```

which is giving me exception :

```
Error: Printing Stack Trace
at printStackTrace (src/mongo/shell/utils.js:37:15)
at DBCollection.aggregate (src/mongo/shell/collection.js:897:9)
at (shell):1:12
Wed Feb 12 16:31:09.515 aggregate failed: {
"errmsg" : "exception: $unwind:  value at end of field path must be an array",
"code" : 15978,
"ok" : 0
} at src/mongo/shell/collection.js:898
```

Help me out how to solve this as I am applying $unwind on an array.

Comment: This perhaps does better if you show the document as represented from the mongo shell rather than a PHP dump. Also, Are you **sure** that **all** allocation elements **are** an Array? That part is well documented.

Comment: `"allocation" : { "1" : { "r_1_a" : 17 } },` . Here is representation in patents collection

Comment: `allocation` is not an array given what you added in your comment. It's a subdocument with a field named `"1"`. Your document saving code isn't saving as an array.

Comment: If it were an array, it would look like this in the console: `"allocation": [{"r_1_a": 17}]`

Comment: I have posted the mongo representation .I am new to mongo and dnt have much knowledge about it. Can you please tell me how to unwind allocation sub-document ?

Comment: The simple answer is: You cannot! You have to ensure, that `allocation` is a "real" array!

Comment: It is an array with custom keys

Answer (score 0):

You have to unwind each nested array level:

```
db.patents.aggregate([
    {'$unwind':'$Patent'},
    {'$unwind':'$Patent.allocation'}
]);
```

**EDIT:**

Looking at what you have posted so far, the reason for the error is that `allocation` is an **object and not an array**. Eventually this is what mongo told you:

```
"errmsg" : "exception: $unwind:  value at end of field path must be an array"
```

Comment: PHP Array. Are you sure?

Comment: Hi heinbo , It is giving me result like this.                          { "result" : [ ], "ok" : 1 }

Comment: Yes Neil this is an array type field with collection named as patents

Comment: What does `db.patents.find().limit(1)` return?

Comment: heinob It is giving me single document

Comment: @user199354 What we are trying to determine is whether your PHP Array type ( which can be a hashmap or array to most people ) is actually a hashmap or an array. If it is a **real** Array the answer should work. But otherwise you have another problem. Hence please post the mongo shell result.

Comment: Neil. It is a real Array . Here is the representation in mongo shell `"allocation" : { "1" : { "r_1_a" : 17 } },`

Comment: Here is a chunk from mongo representation .                         `{ "_id" : ObjectId("52fb18775f44eaaf0a8b462a"), "allocation" : { "1" : { "r_1_a" : 17 } }, "pn" : "US20120101874A1" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52fb18755f44eaaf0a8b4568"), "allocation" : { "1" : { "r_1_a" : 17 } }, "pn" : "US2010372A" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52fb18755f44eaaf0a8b4574"), "allocation" : { "1" : { "r_1_a" : 17 } }, "pn" : "US20120095807A1" }
`

Comment: `allocation` is no `array`. It is an `object` that has a property `"1"`. Which might be a result of mishandling an initial array. Please give me the return document of `db.patents.find().limit(1)`